# Why is this simple Deck.GL OrbitView not interactive?

Tags: deck.gl

I think I'm doing something very basic wrong, or I'm misunderstanding something very fundamental, but I just can't make this respond to mouse events – it's just frozen in its initial view ([Code Pen sample](https://codepen.io/Gutza/pen/WNyjJZx)):

```js
const {Deck, OrbitView, SimpleMeshLayer, COORDINATE_SYSTEM} = deck;
const {CubeGeometry} = luma;

const view = {
    target: [0, 0, 0],
    zoom: 0,
    rotationOrbit: 145,
    rotationX: 65,
    minRotationX: -90,
    maxRotationX: 90,
    minZoom: -10,
    maxZoom: 10
}

deck = new Deck({
  views: new OrbitView({
    orbitAxis: "Y"
  }),
  layers: [
    new SimpleMeshLayer({
      initialViewState: view,
      controller: true,
      data: [
        {
          position: [-25, 0, 0],
          color: [255, 0, 0]
        },
        {
          position: [25, 0, 0],
          color: [0, 255, 0]
        }
      ],
      coordinateSystem: COORDINATE_SYSTEM.CARTESIAN,
      mesh: new CubeGeometry(),
      getPosition: d => d.position,
      getColor: d => d.color,
      getScale: [20, 20, 20]
    })
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I was confused about which properties go where. I left the buggy code here, and fixed it in the Pen, if you want to compare before and after.